How to import Postman collection documentation into Confluence
I have a Postman collection documentation that I want to create a Confluence page with that content. However, I don't know any way to copy the content in the Postman collection documentation into Confluence.
Is there any way to accomplish this without manually copying and editing?

does this help? https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/How-do-you-link-to-a-Postman-collection-from-a-Confluence-page/qaq-p/763509
